# Getting data from a API on the client side without giving the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, axios

Currently I am making a page that display's data gathered from an API. Most of the data is updated on the server side every 4 hours but some of it is updated whenever a client requests the index route. As a result, there is a delay in the index file being sent since the data needs to be updated. I want to gather the updated data after the page has been requested and sent so there is no delay. My first idea was to make the request on the client side which will handle updating the display after the data is gathered but from my knowledge, I don't know how to do that without giving them the API key. Should I approach the problem this way or is there a better way to do it? I'm using Express for the back-end, Axios is used to make the get requests, and EJS is the template engine.

Here is the code:

```
// This is called before the data is send in a for loop
data.gameData[i].player_count = await SteamModule.liveGetCurrentPlayers(data.gameData[i].appid);

res.render('index', {data: data});

// This is the function that is called
liveGetCurrentPlayers: async (id) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${base}/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/?key=${key}&appid=${id}`, {timeout: 1000}).catch(err => {
        Logger.error("Error getting updated user data per request");
        return 'Error';
    });
    if(res.data) {
        return res.data.response.player_count;
    } else {
        return 'Error';
    }
}
```

Comment: simplest seems to be to add a second server in the middle - then you can make your own API keys for clients and pull data 'often' that will be more updated.

Comment: @CFP Support what if making a second server isn't an option?

Comment: I would be tremendously shocked!  If you can pull data from a client and get what you want, then you will need to explain to me how it "isn't an option" to  make a 'server' in the middle (that acts like s client to the API and stores the more current data, then posts that data to clients requesting it from you.)  To get more info, you should post some code and/or at least a flow of the information you are gathering and serving now.

Comment: @CFP Support I'm new to web development so I might have poorly explained what I am trying do to. The information I am requesting from the API needs to be gathered every 4 hours or whenever a user wants to see the page. The data updated every 4 hours is stored in my own database and can be accessed quickly. The data gathered whenever a user wants to see the page causes a delay since it has to make 10-20 requests before sending the client the page. Instead of making the requests before I send the page, I want to send the page and then make those 10-20 requests on either the client or server side

Comment: that sounds like (again, CODE helps....) you are wanting to "paint the page" (so the client sees stuff - though not data, but 'fast load' feeling...) and then load the data.  That is good design and fairly simple to do by loading the minimal css and html to show the 'frame' of the data, then using ajax/javascript to load those 20-ish requests.  If that is what you are saying, then show some code you tried and where you see the slowness - it is much easier to help you then.

Comment: @CFP Support Just added the code. I should probably mention the data variable is declared when the information is pulled from the database.

Comment: OK, so that is pulling data every second....  But, where is the issue of "4 hours"?  I can see from this code that you pull stats (and presume you save it for your clients to see as they like), but there is nothing showing the ISSUE......  If you want help, you have to share the problem - and respond to the things people ask you about....

Comment: @CFP Support The data pulled every 4 hours is working perfectly. I need to change the code pulling the data every second so it happens after res.render is called, hence why I was thinking it would be best to somehow do it from the client side.

Comment: @CFP Support I think I misunderstood what you initially said. Do you mean I should make a request to my own server from the client's end that sends that information?

Comment: Yes.  See my answer for hopefully a clearer picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of a drawing to explain what I've said in comments.....

(the code you showed should constantly update - without other info I can't help with whatever the other issue was, but this is the overall idea....)

[image: General Flow of data for 'server in the middle']

Where:

1. Client requests data from you (your server)
2. Your server sends html and css to show a 'frame' of the page (no data, just something for them to see and feel like something is happening...)
3. Your server requests data from the API server (all the various "20-ish" things you said you wanted to serve....)
4. As the data is updated (or you may have it already), you send the data to the client, updating their 'frame' page with current data.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that. For some reason I misread what you initially said and thought you were talking about something else.

Comment: Like they say "a picture is worth a thousand words" - even if done by as lousy an artist as me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain your keys on the server side and add restriction that those API's can only be accessed by your client side URL. So you would access the API and it will maintain your session and handle the authorized KEY part as well.

Anything and everything on the client side is accessible if it running in your browser.

You can add security measures on the server but not on client side for protecting your key.

Comment: Do you know of any articles or guides that have code examples for this? I don't fully understand what you are saying to do.

Comment: @Adeel is saying the same thing I've been telling you - pull the data into your server and 'serve' it to your clients.....